Synchronize large csv file into DB with dotnet core
I want to develop a batch process in .NET Core to synchronize a CSV file containing 3 million lines. The process reads data from the file, updates existing items in the database, and creates new items if they do not exist. However, this operation currently takes a significant amount of time; for example, processing 100,000 lines takes 30 minutes. I have used parallel tasks to improve performance, but I am still facing latency issues. Is there any solution to reduce this processing time?
Below my code:
 public async Task<bool> ImportDataFromCsvFile()
        {
            try
            {
                // Read CSV file asynchronously
                List<CsvInvoice> data = await _azureBlobService.ReadCsvFileAsync();
                List<InvoiceDb> Invoices = new List<InvoiceDb>();

                // Parallel processing of data to create InvoiceAutoDb list
                Parallel.ForEach(data, Invoice =>
                {
                    var entity = new InvoiceDb
                    {
                        Id_Invoice = Invoice.IdInvoice,
                        DateCheck = Invoice.DateCheck
                    };
                    lock (Invoices) // Ensure thread-safety when adding to the list
                    {
                        Invoices.Add(entity);
                    }
                });

                // Get distinct Invoices
                var distinctInvoice = Invoices
                    .GroupBy(c => c.Id_Invoice)
                    .Where(x => x.Count() == 1)
                    .Select(g => g.First())
                    .ToList();

                var nonDistinctInvoice = Invoices
                    .Except(distinctInvoice)
                    .ToList();

                if (nonDistinctInvoice.Any())
                {
                    Log.Warning("Invoice Dupliqué(s) {duplicata}", nonDistinctInvoice.Select(c => c.Id_Invoice).Distinct());
                }

                // Use Parallel.ForEachAsync for parallel asynchronous processing
//this is the part where it consume time
                await Parallel.ForEachAsync(distinctInvoice, async (Invoice, cancellationToken) =>
                {
                    using (var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope())
                    {
                        var service = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IInvoiceService>();
                        var existingInvoice = await service.GetByNumeroInvoiceAsync(Invoice.Id_Invoice);
                        if (existingInvoice == null)
                        {
                            await service.ImportNewInvoiceAsync(Invoice);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            existingInvoice.DateCheck = Invoice.DateCheck;
                            await service.UpdateImportedInvoiceAsync(existingInvoice);
                        }

                        await service.SaveChangesAsync();
                    }
                });

                Log.Information("{result} line imported successfully", distinctInvoice.Count);

            // Publish to Kafka
            await PublishInvoice(distinctInvoice);

            return true;
        }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Error("Import Data failed {errorMessage}", ex.Message);
        throw new Exception(ex.Message);
    }
}
`


Measure and try to see what’s slow. Also consider using your databases csv loaders

That Parallel.ForEach is probably pointless, creating and adding to the list should be very fast.

The Parallel.ForEach with a lock inside is probably slowing down your code dramatically. You're still calling Invoices.Add(entity) the same number of times and in series, so everything is simply overhead that you don't need.

I'd run your code with standard foreach loops and see if it's faster or just the same.

The first Parallel.ForEach doesn't consume much time for me. The part consuming a large amount of time is with the second Parallel in this line: await Parallel.ForEachAsync(distinctInvoice, async (Invoice, cancellationToken) => ...

@ImaneSab - Probably because it's single threaded and it's issuing each update one SQL statement at a time

@Enigmativity, What do you recommend in this case, or do you have any other approach I can follow?

@ImaneSab - Craft your own SQL command and batch update your data. It will be near instant.

@Enigmativity, I think updating all records at once could be problematic because if there is an issue with a single record, the entire execution might stop. I prefer to log the records with issues and continue processing the valid ones, which is why I handle records individually

@ImaneSab - Run it thru a transaction so it rolls back on error, then bisect your updates to isolate the bad one. That'll give you quite fast updates.

@Enigmativity,Thank you for this solution. I tested it, and it significantly improved the update time. Big Thanks

@ImaneSab - Can you please post this as an answer?

The issue was successfully resolved by implementing the approach of running updates through a transaction to ensure rollback on error, and bisecting the updates to isolate and address the problematic item.This approach was suggested by @Enigmativity, and it successfully resolved the issue as described

 public async Task<(bool isSuccess, List<InvoiceDb> failedItems)> UpsertItemsInBatchesAsync(List<InvoiceDb> items, int batchSize = 1000)
 {
     var failedItems = new List<InvoiceDb>();
     for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i += batchSize)
     {
         var batch = items.Skip(i).Take(batchSize).ToList();
          
         var (batchSuccess, batchFailedItems) = await TryUpsertBatchAsync(batch);

         if (!batchSuccess)
         {
             failedItems.AddRange(batchFailedItems);
         }
     }

     return (failedItems.Count == 0, failedItems);
 }

 private async Task<(bool isSuccess, List<InvoiceDb> failedItems)> TryUpsertBatchAsync(List<InvoiceDb> batch)
 {
     using (var transaction = await _dbContext.Database.BeginTransactionAsync())
     {
         try
         {
             await _dbContext.BulkInsertOrUpdateAsync(batch);
             await transaction.CommitAsync();
             return (true, new List<InvoiceDb>());
         }
         catch
         {
             await transaction.RollbackAsync();
             return (false, await BisectItemsAsync(batch));
         }
     }
 }
 private async Task<List<InvoiceDb>> BisectItemsAsync(List<InvoiceDb> items)
 {
     var failedItems = new List<InvoiceDb>();

     if (items.Count <= 1)
     {
         // If we are down to one item, it's the problematic one
         return items;
     }

     var mid = items.Count / 2;
     var firstHalf = items.Take(mid).ToList();
     var secondHalf = items.Skip(mid).ToList();

     var failedFirstHalf = await UpsertItemsInBatchesAsync(firstHalf, 1);
     var failedSecondHalf = await UpsertItemsInBatchesAsync(secondHalf, 1);

     failedItems.AddRange(failedFirstHalf.failedItems);
     failedItems.AddRange(failedSecondHalf.failedItems);

     return failedItems;
 }

If you have a better implementation, I'm open to it

Can you post the code?

@Enigmativity, i added the code
